# CREATE FUNCTION failed because a column name is not specified for column 1. error for the Multiple parameter of function

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-functions

Wanted to create the multiple parameter of function but it gives me this error:

> CREATE FUNCTION failed because a column name is not specified for
>   column 1.

Code below:

```
create function dmt.Impacted( 
@nameOfColumn varchar ,  @nameOfParam varchar)   
returns table   
as    
return  
(select  
case when '['+@nameOfColumn+']' is null or len(rtrim('['+@nameOfColumn+']')) = 0
then  Convert(nvarchar(2),0) 
else
@nameOfParam end from employee)  ;
```

Comment: Why isnt the error message telling you whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message clearly said, the column in the returned result need a name. Either give it an alias in the `SELECT` like

```
SELECT CASE
       ...
       END a_column_name
       ...
```

or define it in the declaration of the return type as in

```
...
RETURNS TABLE
        (a_column_name nvarchar(max)
...
```

As you can see in the second form you have to specify a data type. As your current code doesn't make much sense now I cannot figure out what is the right one there. You'd need to amend it.

Note, that `len(rtrim('['+@nameOfColumn+']')) = 0` is never true as `len(rtrim('['+@nameOfColumn+']'))` is either `NULL`, when `@nameOfColumn` is `NULL` or at least `2` because of the added brackets.

If `@nameOfColumn` is supposed to be a column name you shouldn't use `varchar` (especially without a length specified for it) but `sysname` which is a special type for object names.

Either way you should define a length for `@nameOfColumn` and `@nameOfParam` as just `varchar` without any length  means `varchar(1)`, which is probably not what you want. And maybe instead of `varchar` you want `nvarchar`.

You may also want to look into [`quotename()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 1):

Define name of column in `SELECT` statement :

```
(select case when '['+@nameOfColumn+']' is null or 
                   len(rtrim('['+@nameOfColumn+']')) = 0
             then  Convert(nvarchar(2),0)
             else  @nameOfParam 
        end as name_column -- define column name
 from employee)
```

Also, your function parameter has no data length, by default it will accept only 1 character  `@nameOfColumn varchar ,  @nameOfParam varchar`  & rest will trim.